# Is there a way to combine several private void button_click into to one?

Tags: c#

Im creating some conditions what will be evaluated when someone click my radiobutton.

At the moment i have about 10 codes that look like below.
The only thing that thange is 102 to 103, 104 and so on.

My idea was to skip having a Private void for each radiobutton click and incorperate it all in to one general. Is there a nice way to achieve this? 
Thanks for your advice.

```
    private void rBtn102_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rBtn102.Checked == true)
        {
            sDepartment = "102";
            updateExampleLabel();
            updateChooseOffer();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about [System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx) you can store relevant data that's unique for each RadioButton under [Tag property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) and query it in universal handler attached to each [RadioButton.Click event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void rBtn102_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
    if (rb == null)
      return; // This is error

    if (rb.Checked)
    {
        sDepartment = (string)rb.Tag;
        updateExampleLabel();
        updateChooseOffer();
    }
}
```

Remember to assign an appropriate Tag to each button in forms designer first.

Comment: Great solution, just what i was looking for. You just introduced me even more to RadioButton properties

Answer (score 2):

What about this? Using single method as EventHandler and check the radiobuttons names,

```
string sDepartment = "";
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rBtn_01.Click += new EventHandler(radio_Click);
    rBtn_02.Click += new EventHandler(radio_Click);
}

public void radio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     RadioButton tempButton = sender as RadioButton;
     switch(tempButton.Name)
     {
           case "rBtn_02":
           sDepartment = "102";
           break;
           case "rBtn_03":
           sDepartment = "103";
           break;
      }
      updateExampleLabel();
      updateChooseOffer();
}
```

Hope helps,